# How to find all possible path in the AON diagram?

Tags: c#

I have to found out all the possible path in the AON Diagram but the problem is I can't link up the project activity according to the diagram.Can anyone help me to figure it out?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use Dijksta's algorithm to make sure you don't get stuck in a loop.  You should have a class for each task.  You project so look like this

```
   public class Task
    {
        static Task root = new Task(); 
        string name;
        DateTime startDate;
        DateTime endDate;
        List<Task> nextTask = new List<Task>();
    }​
```